# Parse Byte array to structure

Tags: c#, node.js

I am sending data byte array (which is converted from structure) C# to Node js, I am unable to parse the array properly in my node js application, below is node js code

```js
var converted = JSON.stringify(msg);
console.log("len : ",converted.length);
var ee = JSON.parse(converted).content.data;
var tt = Buffer.from(ee).toLocaleString('ascii');
console.log(tt);
```

Here I am converting and my C# structure is

```cs
public struct ABC
{
    public string A;
    public Depth[] B;
    public Depth[] C;
    public double D;
    public long E;
    public int F;
    public long G;
}
```

and output is

```
len :  394
B ║YWv]  123EFGH                        N@      O@      H@      H@
```

Comment: Can you also add the code you are using on the node.js side ?

Comment: JSON is html and binary data cannot be sent due to special characters.  Use Convert To 64 base string before sending.

Comment: node js code var converted = JSON.stringify(msg);
console.log("len : ",converted.length);
var ee = JSON.parse(converted).content.data;
var tt = Buffer.from(ee).toLocaleString('ascii');
console.log(tt);

Comment: In Node js I am receving the data through rabbit mq and the received data length is correct but I am unable to parse it. After parsing the output is like "B ║YWv]  123EFGH                        N@      O@      H@      H@", here 123EFGH is correct value but other values are showing different

Comment: Can you add the C# code you are using to convert the strucutre to the byte array

Comment: public static T ByteArrayToStructure<T>(byte[] bytes, int _length, int sourceIndex)
        {
            GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(GetByteAccordingToLength(bytes, _length, sourceIndex), GCHandleType.Pinned);
            T structureType;
            try
            {
                structureType = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(T));
            }
            finally
            {
                handle.Free();
            }

            return structureType;
        }